# Problems writing a Test class for the salesforce OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter class

Tags: apex, unit-test, opportunity, territory-management

I am trying to write a test class for OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter

It implements the `TerritoryMgmt.OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter` and is a **sample class provided by salesforce**. Has any one used this Class before `OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter` ?

If anyone has worked on this before any help, references or suggestions are highly appreciaed ! :)

You can find this class here or below...

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_TerritoryMgmt_OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter.htm

```
    /*** Apex version of the default logic.
* If opportunity's assigned account is assigned to
*  Case 1: 0 territories in active model
*            then set territory2Id =   null
*  Case 2: 1 territory in active model
*            then set territory2Id =   account's territory2Id
*  Case 3: 2 or more territories in active model
*            then set territory2Id =   account's territory2Id that is of highest priority.
*            But if multiple   territories have same highest priority, then set territory2Id = null 
*/
global class OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter implements
TerritoryMgmt.OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter {
     /**
     * No-arg constructor.
     */ 
     global   OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter() {}

     /**
      * Get mapping of   opportunity to territory2Id. The incoming list of opportunityIds contains only those with IsExcludedFromTerritory2Filter=false.
      * If territory2Id =   null in result map, clear the opportunity.territory2Id if set.
      * If opportunity is not present in result map, its territory2Id remains intact.
      */
    global Map<Id,Id> getOpportunityTerritory2Assignments(List<Id> opportunityIds) {
        Map<Id,   Id> OppIdTerritoryIdResult = new Map<Id, Id>();

        //Get the active territory model Id
        Id   activeModelId = getActiveModelId();

        if(activeModelId   != null){
            List<Opportunity>   opportunities =
              [Select Id, AccountId, Territory2Id from Opportunity where Id   IN
              :opportunityIds];
            Set<Id>   accountIds = new Set<Id>();
            //Create   set of parent accountIds
            for(Opportunity opp:opportunities){
                if(opp.AccountId   != null){
                    accountIds.add(opp.AccountId);
                    }
                }

                Map<Id,Territory2Priority> accountMaxPriorityTerritory = 
getAccountMaxPriorityTerritory(activeModelId, accountIds);

            //for each opportunity, assign the highest priority territory if there is 
no conflict, else assign null
            for(Opportunity opp: opportunities){
               Territory2Priority tp = accountMaxPriorityTerritory.get(opp.AccountId);
               //assign highest priority
              territory if there is only 1
              if((tp   != null) && (tp.moreTerritoriesAtPriority == false) && 
(tp.territory2Id != opp.Territory2Id)){
                   OppIdTerritoryIdResult.put(opp.Id, tp.territory2Id);
               }else{
                   OppIdTerritoryIdResult.put(opp.Id,   null);
               }
            }
        }
        return   OppIdTerritoryIdResult;
    }

    /**
      * Query assigned territoryIds in active model for given accountIds
      * Create a map of accountId to max priority territory 
      */
     private Map<Id,Territory2Priority> getAccountMaxPriorityTerritory(Id
activeModelId, Set<Id> accountIds){
        Map<Id,Territory2Priority> accountMaxPriorityTerritory = new 
Map<Id,Territory2Priority>();
        for(ObjectTerritory2Association ota:[Select ObjectId, Territory2Id, 
Territory2.Territory2Type.Priority from ObjectTerritory2Association where objectId IN 
:accountIds and Territory2.Territory2ModelId = :activeModelId]){
            Territory2Priority tp = accountMaxPriorityTerritory.get(ota.ObjectId);

            if((tp   == null) || (ota.Territory2.Territory2Type.Priority > 
tp.priority)){
                //If this is the first territory examined for account or it has 
greater priority than current highest priority territory, then set this as new highest 
priority territory.
                tp = new 
Territory2Priority(ota.Territory2Id,ota.Territory2.Territory2Type.priority,false);
            }else if(ota.Territory2.Territory2Type.priority == tp.priority){
                //The priority of current highest territory is same as this, so set   
moreTerritoriesAtPriority to indicate multiple highest priority territories seen so far.
                tp.moreTerritoriesAtPriority = true;
            }

            accountMaxPriorityTerritory.put(ota.ObjectId,   tp);
        }
        return accountMaxPriorityTerritory;
    }


    /**
     * Get the Id of the Active Territory Model. 
     * If none exists, return   null;
     */
   private Id getActiveModelId() {
       List<Territory2Model>   models = [Select Id from Territory2Model where State = 'Active'];
       Id activeModelId = null;
       if(models.size()   == 1){
           activeModelId = models.get(0).Id;
       }

       return activeModelId;
   }

   /**
    * Helper class to help   capture territory2Id, its priority, and whether there are more territories with same priority assigned to the
 account
    */
   private class Territory2Priority {
       public Id territory2Id { get; set; }
       public Integer priority { get; set; }
       public   Boolean moreTerritoriesAtPriority { get; set; }

              Territory2Priority(Id territory2Id, Integer priority, Boolean moreTerritoriesAtPriority){
           this.territory2Id = territory2Id;
           this.priority = priority;
           this.moreTerritoriesAtPriority = moreTerritoriesAtPriority;
       }
   }
}}
```

My Test class:

```
   **My Test Class :**

       @istest
Private class OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFiltertest{
Private static testmethod void oppTerrAssigntest(){

Opporunity opp =new Opporunity(name='testopporunity');
insert opp;
List<id> opplistid=new List<id>();
opplistid.add(opp.id);

Account acc =new Account(name='testaccount');
insert acc;
Set<id> acclistid=new Set<id>();
opplistid.add(acc.id);


OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter CheckOppty=new OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter();
Map<Id,Id> mapid=CheckOppty.getOpportunityTerritory2Assignments(opplistid);
Map<Id,Territory2Priority>MapTerritory=CheckOppty.getAccountMaxPriorityTerritory(vn897, acclistid)
Id id=CheckOppty.getActiveModelId();


OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter.Territory2Priority innerclass=new OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter.Territory2Priority(Vn897,9908,true);
innerclass.territory2Id;
innerclass.priority;
innerclass.moreTerritoriesAtPriority;

}
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> invalid type : Territory2Priority

Comment: So, have you actually tried writing the test class yourself ? You can't really come here and expect people to do the work for you. That's not how a community works, that's how contractors work. We're all about helping you, helping you learn and figure things out. Feel free to edit the question if you do have a specific question on how to proceed.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke With all due respect, I dont expect you to work for me nor any one for that matter! I don't expect  all ready code from you either ! I ain't a contractor for your info , and not interested in such insinuations provided! I'm just like someone who is new to this topic and expect people to give me reference or  help understanding! I did write Test class for this but stuck in between, I would rather show you the code and ask suggestions if you have any interest in helping people rather than rephrasing the question just because someone said,my question is very straight!! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I've phrased my comment to harsh, but the only straight forward question is see is that you have a class and need a test class. You have not asked how you can do this yourself, or where you can start learning to write test classes, which would be an entirely different question. You say you're trying to write a test class, but have not shared it with us or explained what troubles you're having in writing that class.  If you'd share that, we'd love to help you, but if you don't there's little we can do. Getting helped is a matter of askign the right questions, that's all I wanted to say.

Comment: You can still edit and update the question, so that the community can reopen it.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke I'm glad that you know your phrase was too harsh, no offense taken! This is a  sample class provided by salesforce in the latest Summer 15' release and it is not implemented or released yet, this is something I have never worked on 'Territory Assignment Default logic filter' . Still I tried writing test class and reached somewhere! I take some mistake on myside as well as the question could be understood the other way also which asks test class reference.  I did not understand flagging it as off topic and putting the post on hold!

Comment: anyways Thanks again I have edited the question and provided the test class !

Comment: @SFDC Wolf, I'm running into the exact same thing that you did. Did you ever get this class to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok So the internal class of Territory2Priority ( the type) is noted as Private and you are trying to access this in a test class.

Private will make it only visible inside its class constant.

+1 salesforce here, Add @TestVisible on top of the private and you will be able to access the class from your test.

*Updating the second part*

In the test you are calling the class inside a map MapTerritory
You need to add infront of this call where it site I.E the class name
So your map should look like this

```
Map<Id, OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter.Territory2Priority >MapTerritory=CheckOppty.getAccountMaxPriorityTerritory(vn897, acclistid)
```

Next you are going to get more calls saying could not find methods because they are set to be private. Make them all @TestVisible private Or public.
Finial

```
innerclass.territory2Id;
innerclass.priority;
innerclass.moreTerritoriesAtPriority;
```

Needs to be checked not just called.So these become

```
System.assertEqual(Vn897 ,innerclass.territory2Id, 'Fail');
System.assertEqual(9908 ,innerclass.priority, 'Fail');
System.assertEqual(true ,innerclass.moreTerritoriesAtPriority, 'Fail');
```

Also in the Class the constructor for Territory2Priority is not visible give it ether public or @TestVisible Private

Apologies, Forgot that the class is Global, so inner class must be global.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining.htm

Comment: Hi @Tim , Got it ! I tried doing that but the error still pops up "invalid type : Territory2Priority"

Comment: Is it on saving the test or during run time, If run time could you provide the stack trace

Comment: MapTerritory variable in your test (that you provided ) is missing ;

Comment: Its on saving the test.

Comment: line 21? - Map<Id,Territory2Priority> MapTerritory

should be
Map<Id, CheckOppty.Territory2Priority>MapTerritory

Comment: Tried that as well , The same error "Invalid type: CheckOppty.Territory2Priority"

Comment: Sorry, should be OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter.Territory2Priority
Not the instance you created XD

Comment: Updated the answer to help more. 
If you want anymore info just ask Or if it still isn't working :)

Comment: Thanks Tim for the updated answer, but why is it that instance doesnt work ? well,OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter.Territory2Priority this worked though ! Also, it is asking for a constructor in the first line of inner class "Constructor not defined: [OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter.Territory2Priority].<Constructor> (Integer, Integer, Boolean)" I tried declaring territory2priority @testvisible private and Public dint work either ways...

Comment: Bottom two lines of the answer, Thats something that the Example has missed off. (Needs public or @TestVisible private infront) 

Scope, I belive due to the apex rules it does not have the scope as the constructor would not have made any internal classes. You could create its own instance.

Comment: I tried giving @Testvisible to the concerned class also tried giving Public in front, but still it is showing up error and asking for the constructor. The same error...

Comment: i made them all public and it worked, There are other methods the test is calling make sure the line number didn't move without you noticing

Comment: Tim, I made them all public I even tried @testvisible everywhere in the class! Im getting this error " Constructor not defined: [OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter.Territory2Priority].&lt;Constructor&gt;(Integer, Integer, Boolean) " though am instantiated the class,am getting this error..

Comment: Global class Territory2Priority {
       public Id territory2Id { get; set; }
       public Integer priority { get; set; }
       public   Boolean moreTerritoriesAtPriority { get; set; }
        
           Global Territory2Priority(Id territory2Id, Integer priority, Boolean moreTerritoriesAtPriority)
       {
           this.territory2Id = territory2Id;
           this.priority = priority;
           this.moreTerritoriesAtPriority = moreTerritoriesAtPriority;
       }

Comment: 'Global class' worked ! Though it gives half of the coverage of class, it gives me a sigh of relief finally ! Thanks Tim !  I'm working on the same to improve the coverage, let me know if I have missed out something ! Once again Thanks Tim ! :)

Comment: I would start by changing all the private to Global, The SF code coverage can be funny at the best of times, But i could be down to the system not seeing them to mark as coverage by a test

Comment: Tim, what would be the reason 'Public' or '@TestVisible' not working but global did ? I wonder!!

Comment: Because the class has been given Global rights you cannot change any inner classes access levels to anything else, As for methods it should be fine to give them whatever access level you want. However private will only be visible to its own class. The Code coverage can be funny at times and as there are private methods it could be that even though the methods get called by proxy it does not register the code path though the methods.

Comment: @SFDCWolf could you mark the answer as correct please

Comment: Its my Pleasure Tim!! Thanks!  I'm still working on code coverage it just 50 % of this class...

Answer (score 3):

Since I can't found an OOTB test class for this anywhere, I just wrote one up real quick.

**Requirement in OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter class:**

You will need to mark the inner class and its constructor `@TestVisible`

```
@testVisible
private class Territory2Priority {
    public Id territory2Id { get; set; }
    public Integer priority { get; set; }
    public Boolean moreTerritoriesAtPriority { get; set; }

    @testVisible
    Territory2Priority(Id territory2Id, Integer priority, Boolean moreTerritoriesAtPriority) {
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
public class OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilterTests {


@isTest
static void unitTest() {
    Id opportunityId = [Select Id From Opportunity].Id;
    OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter filter = new OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter();

    Test.startTest();

    Map<Id, Id> resultMap = filter.getOpportunityTerritory2Assignments(new List<Id> {opportunityId});
    OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter.Territory2Priority tp = new OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter.Territory2Priority(opportunityId, 1, false);

    Test.stopTest();

    System.assertEquals(1, resultMap.size());
    System.assertEquals(tp.territory2Id, opportunityId);
    System.assertEquals(1, tp.priority);
    System.assertEquals(false, tp.moreTerritoriesAtPriority);
}

@testSetup
static void setup() {
    Account account = new Account(Name = 'testAccount');
    insert account;

    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
        Name = 'Opportunity',
        CloseDate = System.today().addDays(10),
        StageName = 'Prospecting',
        AccountId = account.Id
    );
    insert opp;
}
}
```

Hopefully this will save somebody a few minutes somewhere down the road.

Comment: - Thanks, I needed that few minutes back in my day. :)

Answer (score -2):

Below is test class which have 92% coverage. but you need to add @TestVisible in apex class for each method.

@isTest
Public class Test_OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter {

```
Public static testmethod void oppTerrAssigntest(){
    
    Account account = new Account(Name = 'testAccount');
    insert account;
    
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
        Name = 'Opportunitytest',
        CloseDate = System.today().addDays(10),
        StageName = 'Discovery & Qualification',
        AccountId = account.Id
    );
    insert opp;
    List<id> opplst   = new List<id>() ;
    opplst.add(opp.id);
    
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    accountIds.add(account.id);
    User usr = [Select id from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
    
    System.RunAs(usr)
    {
        List<Territory2Type> terriType   = [SELECT id, DeveloperName from Territory2Type];
        
        Territory2Model terrModel   = new Territory2Model(DeveloperName='ModelName',Name = 'Name');
        insert terrModel;
        Territory2 objTerr =new Territory2(DeveloperName = 'TestTerritory', Territory2ModelId=terrModel.Id, Name='TestTerritory',Territory2TypeId=terriType[0].Id,Region__c='',Segment__c='',Sub_Region__c='',Theater__c='');
        insert objTerr;
        
        ObjectTerritory2Association objObjectTerritory2Association = new ObjectTerritory2Association(ObjectId = account.Id,Territory2Id =objTerr.Id,AssociationCause='Territory2Manual');
        insert objObjectTerritory2Association;
        
        Test.startTest();
        
        OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter filter = new OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter();
        filter.getOpportunityTerritory2Assignments(opplst);
        Map<Id, Id> resultMap = filter.getOpportunityTerritory2Assignments(new List<Id> {opp.Id});
        filter.getAccountMaxPriorityTerritory(terrModel.id, accountIds);
        filter.getActiveModelId();
        
        Test.stopTest();
        
    }        
}
```

}